# Javascript destroy the current instance of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem with my Canvas project when I open a modal and close it and open another one and make changes to it, all modals that I opened got edited too.

- Like the instances stay in memory I think.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBodyChartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Body Chart</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="all-body-chart-buttons">
                        <div>
                            <button id="btnDraw-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                            <button id="btnEraser-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-eraser" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button id="btnLargeWithLine-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                            <button id="btnMediumWithLine-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 20px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button id="btnSmallWithLine-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 10px; color: black;"></i></button>
                            <button id="btnBlackColor-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button id="btnRedColor-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: #9f3631;"></i></button>
                            <button id="btnBlueColor-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: #00c1ca;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button id="btnUndo-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-undo" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                            <button id="btnRedo-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-redo" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button id="btnClear-edit" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="canvas-box">
                        <canvas id="myCanvas-edit" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="flaticon-cancel-12"></i> Fermer</button>
                    <button id="btnSaveCanvas-edit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
$('.showEditBodyChart').on('click', function(){
            let data = $(this).attr('name');
            data = data.split('$$');
            class SignatureEdit {
                constructor(data) {
                    this.data = data;
                    this.redo_list = [];
                    this.undo_list = [];
                    this.eraser = false;
                    this.color = "#000000";
                    this.sign = false;
                    this.begin_sign = false;
                    this.width_line = 5;
                    this.canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit');
                    this.canvas.width = 750;
                    this.canvas.height = 480;
                    this.offsetLeft = this.canvas.offsetLeft;
                    this.offsetTop = this.canvas.offsetTop;
                    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
                    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
                    this.whenMouseDown();
                    this.whenMouseUp();
                    this.whenMouseMove();
                    this.createSignature();
                    this.clearCanvas();
                    this.resetCanvas();
                    this.changeColorToRed();
                    this.changeColorToBlack();
                    this.changeColorToBlue();
                    this.changeWithLineToSmall();
                    this.changeWithLineToMedium();
                    this.changeWithLineToLarge();
                    this.erase();
                    this.draw();
                    this.undo();
                    this.redo();
                    this.undoEvent();
                    this.redoEvent();
                    this.saveCanvas();
                    this.edit();
                    this.destroyInstance();
                }

                destroyInstance(){
                    document.getElementById("editBodyChartModal").addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
                        delete this;
                    });
                }

                edit(){
                    let img = new Image;
                    img.onload = function(){
                        document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit').getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0, 0); // Or at whatever offset you like
                    };
                    img.src = this.data[1];
                }

                updateMousePosition(mX, mY) {
                    let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let scaleX = this.canvas.width / rect.width;
                    let scaleY = this.canvas.height / rect.height;
                    this.cursorX = (mX - rect.left) * scaleX;
                    this.cursorY = (mY - rect.top) * scaleY;
                }

                whenMouseDown() {
                    document.addEventListener("mousedown", ({
                                                                pageX,
                                                                pageY
                                                            }) => {
                        this.sign = true;
                        this.updateMousePosition(pageX, pageY);
                        // this.context.beginPath();
                        // this.context.moveTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                        // this.context.lineTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                        // this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
                        // this.context.lineWidth = this.width_line;
                        // this.context.stroke();
                    })
                }

                whenMouseUp() {
                    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                        this.sign = false;
                        this.begin_sign = false;
                    })
                }

                whenMouseMove() {
                    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ({
                                                                   pageX,
                                                                   pageY
                                                               }) => {
                        if (this.sign) {
                            this.updateMousePosition(pageX, pageY);
                            this.createSignature();
                        }
                    })
                }

                createSignature() {
                    if (this.erazer){
                        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                    }
                    else{
                        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                    }
                    if (!this.begin_sign) {
                        this.context.beginPath();
                        this.context.moveTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                        this.redo_list = [];
                        this.undo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                        this.begin_sign = true;
                    } else {
                        this.context.lineTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                        this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
                        this.context.lineWidth = this.width_line;
                        this.context.stroke();
                    }
                }

                clearCanvas() {
                    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
                }

                changeColorToRed() {
                    document.getElementById("btnRedColor-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.color = "#9f3631";
                    })
                }

                changeColorToBlack() {
                    document.getElementById("btnBlackColor-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.color = "#000000";
                    })
                }

                changeColorToBlue() {
                    document.getElementById("btnBlueColor-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.color = "#00c1ca";
                    })
                }

                changeWithLineToSmall(){
                    document.getElementById("btnSmallWithLine-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.width_line = 5;
                    })
                }

                changeWithLineToMedium(){
                    document.getElementById("btnMediumWithLine-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.width_line = 10;
                    })
                }

                changeWithLineToLarge(){
                    document.getElementById("btnLargeWithLine-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.width_line = 20;
                    })
                }

                erase(){
                    document.getElementById("btnEraser-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.erazer = true;
                    })
                }

                draw(){
                    document.getElementById("btnDraw-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.erazer = false;
                        this.width_line = 5;
                    })
                }

                resetCanvas() {
                    document.getElementById("btnClear-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                        this.erazer = false;
                        this.redo_list = [];
                        this.uno_list = [];
                        this.clearCanvas();
                    })
                }

                undo(){
                    if (this.undo_list.length){
                        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                        this.redo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                        var restore_state = this.undo_list.pop();
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = restore_state;
                        var width = this.canvas.width;
                        var height = this.canvas.height;
                        img.onload = function() {
                            document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                            document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                        }
                    }
                }

                redo(){
                    if(this.redo_list.length){
                        this.undo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                        var restore_state = this.redo_list.pop();
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = restore_state;
                        var width = this.canvas.width;
                        var height = this.canvas.height;
                        img.onload = function() {
                            document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                            document.getElementById('myCanvas-edit').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                        }
                    }
                }

                undoEvent() {
                    document.getElementById("btnUndo-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.undo();
                    })
                }

                redoEvent() {
                    document.getElementById("btnRedo-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        this.redo();
                    })
                }

                saveCanvas(){
                    document.getElementById("btnSaveCanvas-edit").addEventListener("click", () => {
                        var id = this.data[0];
                        var dataURL = this.canvas.toDataURL();
                        var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                        });
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/bodycharts/' + id,
                            data: {
                                '_method': 'PUT',
                                '_token': csrf_token,
                                canvas: dataURL
                            }
                        }).done(function () {
                            swal({
                                title: 'Succés!',
                                text: "Diagramme corporel a été modifié avec succés!!",
                                type: 'success',
                                padding: '2em'
                            });
                            window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1000)
                        }).fail(function () {
                            swal({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Oops...',
                                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                                padding: '2em'
                            })
                        });
                    })
                }

            }
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            new SignatureEdit(data);

            $('#editBodyChartModal').modal('show');
        });
```

I added this event to destroy the current instance when the modal is close, but it doesn't work.

```
destroyInstance(){
                    document.getElementById("editBodyChartModal").addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
                        delete this;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve] -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)